Node startup too slow
I'm starting a new node, with no voting, only to query for transactions.
The node is working properly, but when i attach a geyser plugin, the node startup becomes too slow, the normal startup time, is about 15 min, but with the --geyser-plugin-config flag is more than 4 hours, i don't know what to do, i've tried different geyser plugins, yellowstone grpc, jito grpc, and right now a plain empty developed by me, with the same results.
In the logs i see the plugins are started, but only solana metrics entries in the log during 2-3 hours.
thats me start-validator config :
#!/bin/bash
exec solana-validator 
--identity /home/sol/validator-keypair.json 
--known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 
--known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ 
--known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ 
--known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S 
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d 
--no-snapshot-fetch 
--only-known-rpc 
--no-voting 
--private-rpc 
--full-rpc-api 
--log /home/sol/solana-validator.log 
--ledger /mnt/ledger 
--accounts /mnt/accounts 
--snapshots /mnt/ledger 
--rpc-port 8899 
--gossip-port 8001 
--rpc-bind-address 127.0.0.1 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
--limit-ledger-size

Please i need help
